# How to enable pasting old entries from clipboard in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, clipboard

The text-fields in flutter allow you to toggle the ability to hit paste, but that only lets you paste the last thing in the clipboard? Is there any way to allow users to paste older entries from the clipboard like in all other text-fields?

I tried to search for anything like that, but all resources spoke only about the paste option

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.